# Syntax: Single statement in function declaration

Tags: c, syntax

In the C programming language, it is possible to omit a code block in the case of a single statement, for example:

```
if(1) exit();
```

Now, does this only apply to conditionals ?
Why is this not valid in the case of functions:

```
void f(int a) exit();
```

Comment: Because the standard says so?

Comment: never tried it, but I suppose that, if it is not allowed, it is just a matter of syntax, maybe legacy: once you would have written void f(a) int a; { ... }, so the { } were needed to mark the end of argument type declaration block ... maybe...

Comment: thanks, I knew of the old function syntax, but this also means compilers are able to correctly parse this then..

Comment: compilers are able to correctly parse that (at least, gcc can).

Comment: See this related question, asking the same question about C#: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016654/why-do-methods-with-only-one-statement-need-braces/6019199#6019199

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's a feature of C syntax. In [BNF](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form), a function definition is something like

```
FUNC_DEF ::= TYPE IDENTIFIER "(" PARAM_LIST ")" BLOCK
```

while a statement is

```
STATEMENT ::= (EXPRESSION | DECLARATION | CONTROL | ) ";" | BLOCK
BLOCK ::= "{" STATEMENT* "}"
```

(simplifying to allow intermixed declarations and statements, which C++ allows but C doesn't), and an `if` statement is

```
CONDITIONAL ::= "if" "(" EXPRESSION ")" STATEMENT
```

omitting the `else` part for now.

The **reason** for this is that otherwise, you could write the function

```
void no_op() {}
```

as

```
void no_op();
```

but the latter syntax is already in use to denote a declaration.

Comment: I think it's intrasting question from the C parser point of view. Because I dont see any contradiction in the second statment for parser. But any way +1

Comment: Thanks ! This is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for, and you remind me why I like CS !

Comment: The `int no_op() {}` as `no_op()` looks more confusing.

Comment: Though you could forbid the `void no_op();` syntax for definitions, e.g. `FUNC_DEF ::= TYPE IDENTIFIER "(" PARAM_LIST ")" (BLOCK|STATEMENT)`. But that would be really confusing to newbies and even apprentices.

Comment: @phresnel: I updated the `STATEMENT` rule to more accurately reflect C syntax; `;` by itself is a valid statement, so your suggestion would not work.

Comment: @larsmans: My post was exactly about your `STATEMENT` ;) You could still make special kludges like `STATEMENT ::= (FOO| ) ";" | BLOCK` and then `FOO ::= EXPRESSION | DECLARATION | CONTROL`, but as said, I would find it too confusing for the language.

Answer (score 4):

- The syntax of a conditional statement is this:

  ```
  if(expression) statement
  ```
- A compound statement is a statement.
- A `compound statement` is defined as

  ```
  { zero or more statements }
  ```
- The syntax of a function definition is this

  ```
   function_declaration compound_statement
  ```
- So, by definition a function body must be a compound statement and have `{}`
- ***QED*** :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a very old dialect of C, the K&R C. In this dialect the function declaration may look like this:

```
fun_a(a,b)
char a;
float b;
{
        fun_b(b,a);
}
```

I think it would be too hard to parse it without `{` and `}`.

Comment: This is probably the historical reason, +1, but there's also a reason why the syntax hasn't changed in ANSI C.