# I,m unable to figure out the error "expected ";" after top-level indicator."

Tags: c, cs50

I,m unable to figure out the error **" expected ";" after top-level indicator"**. I cant understand the error.

ERROR
test.c:5:15: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
int main(void)
^
;
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
2 errors generated.
make: *** [: test] Error 1

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cs50.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void)
string username;


typedef struct
{
   string name;
   string number;
}
phnbk;

{
   phnbk contact[2];
   contact[0].name = "david";
   contact[0].number = "123456789";

   contact[1].name = "victor";
   contact[1].number = "9987654321";

   username = get_string("enter your name: ");

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 2; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(contact[i].name,username) == 0)
        {
            printf("your number is %s" , contact[i].number);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Something missing after `int main(void)`

Comment: You can't declare Main without parentheses or ;

you wrote int main(void) // no ; or {} afterwards

Comment: The single line containing `int main(void)` should be moved down after the line closing the struct alias `phnbk;` and before the `{` that follows. That single change should allow this to compile, though whether it runs correctly or not is unrelated.

Comment: This is one reason why it is actually required (!) to produce a [mcve]. At some point, I'm sure you would have found that typo yourself!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `main` function must be within `{}`
Something like:

```
string username;
typedef struct
{
   string name;
   string number;
}
phnbk;
    
int main(void)
{
   phnbk conta      
   ....
```

Answer (score 1):

[Functions cannot be defined without braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034423/why-are-curly-braces-in-functions-not-optional-in-c-style-languages) (`{}`). `main()` is no exception, which is causing the error.

Therefore, you must define your main function like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    string username;
}
```

You have another block of code in `{}` later, outside of any function, which is not allowed (citation needed). You likely meant to include that code in `main()`, like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cs50.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct
{
   string name;
   string number;
}
phnbk;

int main(void)
{
   string username;
   phnbk contact[2];
   contact[0].name = "david";
   contact[0].number = "123456789";

   //Other main() stuff

}
```

Comment: _"(The two syntaxes are functionally identical, but which one to use is controversial)":_ There are no two syntaxes here, just two different formatting styles.