# Why do I need braces in a property

Tags: c#, properties, get, set, curly-braces

I have this property

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The production date of the device is contained in its serial number.
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime Date
    {
        get 
        {
            return SerialNumber.Date;
        }
    }
```

However, I would expect I could write it like this

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The production date of the device is contained in its serial number.
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime Date
    {
        get return SerialNumber.Date;
    }
```

But I receive the error `{ or ; expected`.

Now my question is: Why do I need braces here, while I do not wish to mark the beginning and end of a scope, as there is only one line of code.

It doesn't really matter that I do need to use braces. But in my opinion its not consistent with the rest of the interpretation of C# code.

You can use 
`if(DoNotUseBraces) return null;` for example, no braces necessary.
Or even

```
if (SomeBoolean)
    return null;
```

Again, no braces necessary. I guess its the same as: [Why do methods with only one statement need braces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016654/why-do-methods-with-only-one-statement-need-braces) but get does not implement the () like `get()` e.g.

Comment: Classes and methods need braces too, as do `try`/`catch`/`finally` and a few other constructs. There's often little reason behind such things (and properly following coding conventions make those idiosyncrasies a moot point anyway).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those brackets are not for a scope block, it's part of the syntax. The setter and getter are actually methods, so it's similar to the syntax for a function.

For an `if` statement the brackets are not part of the syntax:

```
if (<condition>) <statement>
```

For a property getter, the brackets is part of the syntax:

```
<type> <identifier> { get { <statements> } }
```

just as they are for a function:

```
<type> <identifier>(<parameters>) { <statements> }
```

Answer (score 3):

Because a property in C# can also have a setter:

```
public DateTime Date
{
    get return SerialNumber.Date;
    set SerialNumber.Date = value;
}
```

That would not work. Where does the getter end and where does the setter begin?

These scopes are clear even if you'd add multiple lines:

```
public DateTime Date
{
    get { return SerialNumber.Date; }
    set { SerialNumber.Date = value; }
}
```

> Now my question is: Why do I need braces here, while I do not wish to
>   mark the beginning and end of a scope, as there is only one line of
>   code.

I assume that it was just too much work for the C# compiler team to implement something that is just a nice-to-have for a one liner property.

Comment: `Where does the getter end and where does the setter begin?` as its on one line I do not see the problem of that.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a language design, is considered in that way. It's like concerning about fact that Lamborghini car has doors that opens to up and not to side like other cars. It's all about language design.

For complete Jon Skeet answer on this question, pointing to exact location of language specification that describes this, can have a look on:

[Why this compile error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823427/why-this-compile-error)

Comment: To me it looks more like the implementation of (to stick with your example) a lamborghini car with one door that opens upwards, and one door that opens sideways.

Comment: @MikedeKlerk: no it's not, please have a look on the link provided.